# How to convert datetime string from MVC controller to JQuery datetime?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass current system date from a controller to a view using .NET MVC. The controller code is like:

```
 public DateTime DateTimeReturn()
 {
     return DateTime.Now;
 }
```

In the view I am trying to capture the current time:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "DateTimeReturn",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        d1 = result;
    }
});

d2 = new Date(Date.parse(d1));
```

The result (d1) returns "**14/09/2023 18:51:06**". But when I am trying to parse it to datetime like **new Date(Date.parse(d1))** it is giving error like "Invalid Date". When I am using JavaScript to return the current date like **Date.parse(new Date)**, it returns the current date like "**Thu Sep 14 2023 19:54:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**". The current datetime format of the server-side controller and jQuery are different. I need the date in integer format (like 1694697943000) to proceed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)